# endeca filter not equal to condition

Tags: pipeline, endeca

I need to filter a set of records based on a 'not equal to' (NEQ) condition.
For example if I want get all products where brand is not equal to say "X".
How to configure this situation in pipeline?

Comment: Do you want to keep them out of the index, create a property for them, or keep them out of a specific result set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a previous answer, you can use a `Record Filter`, which is the `Nr` parameter, to accomplish this. You can read more about `Record Filters` in the [Advanced Developer Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28910_01/MDEX.622/pdf/AdvDevGuide.pdf).

Since the question is specifically about configuring the pipeline to support this, it is worth pointing out that you have to explicitly enable properties for `Record Filter` while all dimensions are automatically available for `Record Filter`. In most cases 'Brand' is likely to be a dimension, in which case your query will look like this:

```
Nr=NOT(brand:X)
```

It is likely you'll want to take this further to use nested filters which I suggest you look at the examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `URLEneQuery` use: `Nr=NOT(property.brand: X)`